# How does mongoose know what collection I am accessing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a trouble grasping a concept in Mongoose.

I'm using MongoDB atlas, got a cluster , a database and 2 collections.

users, characters.

Through a guide I've learned that a good way to write your stuff is to have a model (I use the naming schema) as a file, importing it into your Database module/class

and using it there to perform a query...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const process = require("./config.env");

db = () => {
  return mongoose
    .connect(process.env.URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: true,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(`Connected to Databse : ${response.connection.host}`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("DB_ERROR:", err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};

module.exports = db;
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

```
const User = require("../schemas/User");
const db = require("../config/db");
class Database {
  constructor(db, collection) {
    this.db = db;
    this.collection = collection;
    this.User = User;
  }

  connect() {
    return db();
  }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

one file to handle the db connection..another file as the User schema and a third file to handle every function i might use globally...

One thing I cannot wrap my mind around is

how is the findOne() function able to locate the collection I am using without me telling it what collection i want it to search in?

is it somehow translating the

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

line and searching for "users" as well? I just can't understand the magic behind this...

what if I want to search specifically in the characters collection...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongoose uses the model name, as passed when it was created: `mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)`, converted to lower case and with an 's' appended.

For the model `User` it uses the collection `users` by default.  You can change this by explicitly specifying the collection name in the schema.

Comment: So let's say I want to access the character collection? I just change the "User" to "Character" with a different schema?

Comment: Exactly.  Or use the [collection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) option to specify which MongoDB collection name to use.